# Python List methods

Tags: python, list, function, call

I had to make a text processing in Python.

So I created a class `TextProcessing`:

```
manipulator = TextProcessing("one two three four four")
repr(manipulator) => "one two three four four"
manipulator["four"]  //=> [3, 4] => I made a list for that
```

But after that I had to make a function like that:

```
manipulator.two.replace("second") => "one second three four four"
```

I have no idea how to link the two here with my list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can play with overriding [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s
    def replace(self, x):
        self.s = self.s.replace(self.x, x)
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        self.x = name
        return self

a = A('abc')
a.b.replace('X')
print a.s
```

or

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def replace(self, x):
        self.x.s = self.x.s.replace(self.y, x)
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return B(self, name)

a = A('abc')
a.b.replace('X')
print a.s
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I have an another question : How can i get multiple attributes with getattr ?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not that easy